# navigate in window without navigating the camera

Tags: 3d-view, navigation

I am having a weird problem with my navigation. The issue occurred just today without changing any of my settings: I am looking through the camera (Numpad 0), and I want to navigate/zoom in and out within the WINDOW, without changing the camera perspective. Normally I click on a non-interactive area in the window and scroll (screenshot1). Then I can get closer to the object without changing the camera position. For some reason, this does not work anymore. Each time I am scrolling, I manipulate the position of the camera itself, which is very annoying. In my example (see screenshot2), the camera moves away from the cube, which should not be the case. Thank you for your help.

[image: Screenshot1]

[image: Screenshot2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is "lock camera to view" enabled? (Right toolbar in 3D viewport > view > view lock)

[image]

Comment: oh yes!!! thnx!